# How to search for a part of the string based on start and the end with regex?

Tags: python, regex

My string looks like:

```
s = ' {"start": 2542, "end": 2546, "text": "Asia", "labels": ["LOC"]}]'
```

I am trying to get the "LOC" part in labels. I tried:

```
re.match(r'"labels": [".*\"]$', s).group()
```

but got an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: You wanted to write it as [`m = re.search(r'"labels": \["([^][]*)\"]', s)`](https://ideone.com/9NKDjI).

Comment: `re.match` matches the pattern at the beginning of the string; `re.search` searches through the entire string (and can match anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
s = ' {"start": 2542, "end": 2546, "text": "Asia", "labels": ["LOC"]}]'
m = re.search(r'"labels": \["(.*)\"]', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See [Python proof](https://ideone.com/ndKk9d) and [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/4rerCs/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "labels":                '"labels": '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \"                       '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```